How does Edge manage and store cookies?
I'm trying to figure out how Edge works with cookies. For example when I authenticate on Azure Portal it will store cookies and allow me to log on while the cookie is valid. The thing is that even if I log out and delete cookies on Edge interface I see that it's retrieving these cookies again and allowing me to log on to the portal again without providing credentials. Even when I delete it on the file system  (C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User\Data\Default\Network\Cookies) the authentication cookies show up again when I restart Edge. I thought that this was the way a browser would store cookies, on a unique file and that's how Chrome does but it looks like Edge is different. So how is that possible? I'm trying to implement MFA on an application that is using Edge via Webview2 and can't simply emulate an authentication because it's retrieving the authentication cookies from somewhere I can't even find.

Are you logging into another account on Edge, and does Edge then retrieve or recreate those cookies using that account information? Could Nirsoft's ChromeCookiesView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cookies_view.html (for current Edge versions), and EdgeCookiesView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/edge_cookies_view.html (for pre-2019 Edge), help?

@DrMoishePippik, no, It's not necessary to log in to create the cookies, it just log in with with the cookies it's retrieving even though I've deleted cookies on the browser GUI and current user Appdata. Thanks for the app, it's showing the cookies are still there when I delete them but unfortunatly it doesn't show the physical location (ie: filename, folder, etc) of those cookies.

The location is shown in Options | Advanced Options. For example, Edge cookies are in C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Network\Cookies Brave Browser cookies are at C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\Default\Network\Cookies

@DrMoishePippik Hi and thank you for taking the time. I've already deleted this file (edge), the problem is that the browser still retrieves cookies. For example, for portal.azure.com, I delete every cookie on Edge in multiple ways available and they still come back. Now I noticed that it happens to portal.azure.com and not to yahoo email for example. Might be something related to Azure but I still find it weird.
